# Windows authentication in Java

Tags: c#, java, .net, wcf, authentication

I am developing a java application (running on a Linux server) that needs to connect to a .net WCF web service configured to use Windows authentication only. It seems to work fine when I run the app on my Windows desktop. Is there any way to make it work from the Linux server?

Answer (score 0):

[HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) supports [NTLM authentication](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/ntlm.html), so I suggest using that.