# Windows services authentication using Kerberos from Java program on linux

Tags: java, linux, reporting-services, kerberos

Hie everyone, I am struggling with a problem of authentication for a few days now. I work on a web app on tomcat7/java7/linux and I need to access a Windows SSRS server from this app.

When I run the code on my windows machine, everything work just fine, authentication is done by Windows and I just use:

```
InputStream pdfInStream = new BufferedInputStream(pdfUrl.openStream(), bufferSize);
```

On the linux server, I use Kerberos through GSS-API javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext and I am able to authenticate against the Kerberos server: LoginContext .login() works just fine.

And now I am stuck here, [Windows authentication in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298066/windows-authentication-in-java) suggest a deprecated tool, Oracle documentation kept me days without getting to the point, SPNEGO (http://spnego.sourceforge.net/) doesn't seem to address my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Refs:
Oracle documentation:
docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/BasicClientServer.html
docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/ClientServer.html
docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/AcnAndAzn.html

HTTP tools from apache: http://hc.apache.org/

Comment: There is a custom authentication scheme in ssrs that would allow more flexibility for your project only if you have control of the ssrs server. If not you will probally need to look into 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can have some control over the SSRS server and I will look into it.

However If possible I would like to use the kerberos windows authentication provided in place of NTLM in my company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hie everyone!

I solved my problem using a different mean. I authenticated from my client using NTLM (but Kerberos is also possible with this library) even if I run on a linux machine. It is all possible thanks to Apache HTTPComponents library.

If you have the same problem, I recommend you to stop by:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/authentication.html#ntlm .

See ya!